# Continuous image of $(0, 1)$ equal to half-closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for an example of a continuous map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which maps $(0, 1)$ to some $(a, b]$.

I also would like to find such a map where the image of $(0, 1)$ is instead some $[a, b)$.

I know that the image must be an interval, and I see no reason why such maps could not exist.

But while $(-1, 1)$ admits an easy example (e.g., take $f(x)={x^2}$), I can't find one for $(0,1)$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: $(x-1/2)^2?\,\,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a shifted parabola such as $$ y=(x-1/2)^2$$ for the first part and its reflection $$ y=-(x-1/2)^2$$ for the second question?

Of course you may change the power to any even positive integer as well.

Comment: To the proposer: If $f$ maps $(0,1)$ onto $(a,b]$ then $g(x)=a+b-f(x)$ maps $(0,1)$ onto $[a,b)$..... If $b>a$ then the  function $f(x)=b- 2(b-a)|x-1/2|$ maps $(0,1)$ onto $(a,b].$